# App keeps crashing after update from google play

Tags: android, google-play, androidx

I've updated my android app to use androidx support libs, when running locally everything works fine, runnings automatic tests with google also works.
The problems started to happen when users updated in google play that it just keeps crashing. Uninstalling and reinstalling the app solves the problem.

I have also had a hard time reproducing this locally but I have access to a phone that keeps crashing with the updated version from google play.

From what I can tell the problem has to do with inflating a view

```
2019-03-27 09:58:58.667 1975-1975/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp.android, PID: 1975
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:658)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:64)
    at com.android.internal.policy.HwPhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(HwPhoneLayoutInflater.java:107)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:731)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:799)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:976)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:877)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:877)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:974)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.f.b(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.c.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:141)
    at com.myapp.android.ui.main.MainActivity.G(MainActivity.java:1224)
    at com.myapp.android.ui.main.MainActivity.a(MainActivity.java:106)
    at com.myapp.android.ui.main.MainActivity$2.a(MainActivity.java:291)
    at com.myapp.android.ui.main.MainActivity$2.onChanged(MainActivity.java:283)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.b(LiveData.java:113)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.a(LiveData.java:131)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.b(LiveData.java:289)
    at androidx.lifecycle.p.b(MutableLiveData.java:33)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:91)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0400b4 a=-1}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:996)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:980)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4746)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:597)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:237)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:233)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:229)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:658) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:64) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.HwPhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(HwPhoneLayoutInflater.java:107) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:731) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:799) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:976) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:877) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:877) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:974) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.f.b(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.c.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:141) 
    at com.myapp.android.ui.main.MainActivity.G(MainActivity.java:1224) 
    at com.myapp.android.ui.main.MainActivity.a(MainActivity.java:106) 
    at com.myapp.android.ui.main.MainActivity$2.a(MainActivity.java:291) 
    at com.myapp.android.ui.main.MainActivity$2.onChanged(MainActivity.java:283) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.b(LiveData.java:113) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.a(LiveData.java:131) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.b(LiveData.java:289) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.p.b(MutableLiveData.java:33) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:91) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

I'm not sure if the lines is correct but the error happens here

```
 private void initMainActivity() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

I've tried to really go through the app to make sure that we are not referencing any old support libs.
Also have set

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

without any result.

Any ideas since we are getting a bit lost here.

This only happens when updating to this version from google play, not when testing the app locally och by doing a clean install, confirmed on several devices and os versions.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.myapp.android.ui.main.MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/activity_top_section" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:elevation="-1dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/bottom_bar_height"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/activity_bottom_section"
        layout="@layout/activity_bottom_section" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

activity_top_section.xml

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/toolbar_height"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/activity_top_section_toolbar_search"
            layout="@layout/activity_top_section_toolbar_search" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_image"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/search_image_view_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_view_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_black"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            style="@style/FontText.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

activity_bottom_section.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_bar_parent_height"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/shadow_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_margin_extra_large"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow" />

    <com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_bar_height"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?attr/colorBgLight"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/navigation_icon_color"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: please add your `activity_main.xml` file

Comment: added xml file above

Comment: also `activity_top_section` and `activity_bottom_section`

Comment: also check  line #17 in `activity_main.xml`

Comment: added more code for the layouts

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0400b4 a=-1}`

Comment: yes but what does that mean? And how does updating the app vs reinstalling the app make any difference?